# Invalid certificate for one specific website

Tags: macos, google-chrome, security, ssl, certificate

When trying to navigate to a specific website (amazon.com in my case) I always get the "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" error in Chrome (and equivalent errors in Safari/other browsers). All other websites work. I'm on Mac OSX 10.15, when clicking to see the cert I can see that it's trying to associate it with the wrong website (register.be.xfinity.com instead of amazon.com) - see screenshot:

[image]

The background story is that my internet access modem was temporarily disabled and always routed all browser access to that xfinity "activation" website (walled garden) and I guess at some point I clicked approve to update the cert from that fake website, or something similar, I can't recall. I tried removing the Digital Guardian cert from keychain and adding it back (importing exported one and marking it as trusted) but it didn't help.

How can I fix the issue? Help!

Thanks!

Comment: Certificates of servers are not cached. But it might be that the browser has still cached a redirect to the xfinity activation site and is following this redirect. I recommend to clear all caches in the browser and maybe also restart the computer to clear any DNS caches.

Comment: Does seem like a DNS cache issue, which is cached at the Mac level, I think, which would explain why all browsers do it.  I assume that Incognito mode does it too?  Read a blog like https://macpaw.com/how-to/clear-dns-cache-on-mac and try `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` to flush the DNS cache.

Comment: Amazon doesn’t use Xfinity to sign their TLS certificates.  Your ISP is performing a man in the middle attack on your connection.  Try removing your chrome user profile